# Why the word "Salt" is used as terminology in Encryption Algorithm

Tags: encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is a password salt called a “salt”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244903/why-is-a-password-salt-called-a-salt)

As the title said, why the word "Salt" is used as terminology in Encryption Algorithm?

Isn't that **Salt** is a kind of food ingredient? What is the relationship of this food ingredient with Encryption?

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).  It is additional input that helps to perturb the encryption making it just that much more difficult to break.

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question, does it ?

Comment: Where does the name come from? - I would see the link provided by @mjb